# ng-content is not working inside select tag Angular2

Tags: angular

i am trying to make a custom dropdown component but when i try to access data through ng-content inside select tag its not working.

this is my custom-component html file:

```
<select class="form-control">

    <ng-content></ng-content>

</select>
```

this is my main html file where i am calling the component:

```
<dropdown>
        <option value="">Select details type</option>
        <option value="">Personal</option>
        <option value="">General</option>
        <option value="">Contact</option>
        <option value="">Settings</option>
 </dropdown>
```

what i am doing wrong ???

Comment: Checkout PrimeNG dropdown as a working example. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently angular2 uses native (browser) HTML parser. According to the standard only [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/optgroup.html#optgroup) and [`<option>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option) HTML elements are permitted inside [`<select>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html) element (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html#select-content-model)). At least Chrome removes all other HTML tags. Try to execute the next code in Chrome:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<select><ng-content></ng-content></select>';
console.log(div.innerHTML) // "<select><select>"
```

So, at the time angular2 will start to process the markup, `<ng-content>` will be already removed.

This issue can be resolved after (and if) [angular2 team implements its own HTML parser](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4417)